# Regular expression that defnes the set of all words

Tags: discrete-mathematics, regular-expressions

I'm trying to write a regular expression that defines the set of all words written in lower case characters and digits that contain a binary number.

My idea:

$(\varepsilon |[a-z]^{*})(\varepsilon |(0|1)^{*})(\varepsilon |[a-z]^{*})(\varepsilon |(0|1)^{*})$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: You don't need the empty string if you have *, it means 0 or more.

Comment: Maybe better suited to [cs.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: As @Jared points out, your expression reduces to $$[a-z]^*(0\mid 1)^*[a-z]^*(0\mid 1)^*\;.$$ This matches any string of lower-case letters, any string of binary digits, any string of binary digits before or after a string of lower-case letters, any string of binary digits between two strings of lower-case letters, any string of lower-case letters between two strings of binary digits, and any word consisting of a string of lower-case letters followed by a string of binary digits followed by a string of lower-case letters followed by another string of binary digits. This probably isn’t ...

Comment: ... quite what you want.